# Apply filter in the rest services methods with @NameBinding

Tags: java, rest, maven, weblogic, jersey-2.0

I am trying to apply authentication to a few methods of rest services. So apply the annotation @NameBinding for reference to the class of the filter that will validate the authentication, but when doing the test the service passes the filter (it never enters to validate) showing "El msn es...", when it should return 401 Unauthorized .

NameBinding class:

```
package api.movil.token;

import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;


@Retention(value = RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
@NameBinding
public @interface JWTTokenNeeded {
}
```

Filter class:

```
package api.movil.token;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import api.movil.util.KeyGenerator;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Key;


@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
@JWTTokenNeeded
public class JWTTokenNeededFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("entro --------------->");
        String authorizationHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        System.out.println("#### authorizationHeader : " + authorizationHeader);

        if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            System.out.println("#### invalid authorizationHeader : " + authorizationHeader);
            throw new NotAuthorizedException("Authorization header must be provided");
        }

        String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer".length()).trim();

        try {
            // Validate the token
            KeyGenerator keyGenerator=new KeyGenerator();
            Key key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(key).parseClaimsJws(token);
            System.out.println("#### valid token : " + token);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("#### invalid token : " + token);
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
        }
    }
}
```

Rest service class:

```
package api.movil.servicios;

@Path("/users")
public class UserEndpoint {

    @POST
    @Path("/getPrueba")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @JWTTokenNeeded
    public Response getPrueba(@FormParam("msn")String msn){
        System.out.println(msn);
        return Response.ok("El msn es "+msn).build();
    }
}
```

Class of configuration:

```
package api.movil.servicios;

import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import api.movil.token.JWTTokenNeededFilter;
import api.movil.util.ExceptionHandler;

@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ApplicationConfigura extends Application {

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return getRestClasses();
    }

    //Auto-generated from RESTful web service wizard
    private Set<Class<?>> getRestClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();        
        resources.add(UserEndpoint.class);
        resources.add(JWTTokenNeededFilter.class);
        resources.add(ExceptionHandler.class);
        return resources;    
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

I am using the weblogic application server.

Comment: I am struggling with same problem.

Comment: I have solved the problem by changing the Weblogic version.
Now I am using version 12.2.1.2.0

Comment: can you please elaborate it a little bit. I am using tomcat apache 9 server.